# How to download an image and then serve Next.js api routes

Tags: node.js, api, https, next.js, fs

How can I download an image and then serve in Next.js api routes.

This is my current example, what am I missing?

```
import https from 'https'
import fs from 'fs'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(`image.jpg`)
    const request = https.get(imageUrl, function(response) {
      response.pipe(file).on('close', function () {
        console.log('File written!')
      });
    });
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')
    res.send(file)
}
```

I am currently getting this error: `Error [ERR_STREAM_CANNOT_PIPE]: Cannot pipe, not readable`

Comment: You have two levels of callbacks before the file is ready to send, so you need to move the code that sends the file inside the innermost callback (after `console.log('File written')`).